# Outlook web add-in How to get customer properties via EWS in JS

Tags: office-js, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

How to get customer properties via EWS in JS if I saved them via Outlook JS. API

1. I saved custom properties using the following JS code:

   ```
      Office.context.mailbox.item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync(callback);

         function callback(asyncResult) {
         var customProps = asyncResult.value;
         customProps.set("isSync", "test");

        // Save custom properties via JS API
        customProps.saveAsync(saveCallback);
       }
   ```
2. Then I would like to get this custom prosperity via EWS.

Case 1:

```
   '<t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertySetId="cecp-my manifest" PropertyName="isSync" PropertyType="String"/>'
```

Case 2:

```
   '<t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="isSync" PropertyType="String"/>'
```

Both approaches does not work. How should I describe <t:AdditionalProperties>?

At the same time everything works if I use .Net:

```
 ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedPropertyDefinition = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "cecp-my manifest", MapiPropertyType.String);
 var props = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.MimeContent, extendedPropertyDefinition);'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property definition should be

```
'<t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="cecp-my manifest" PropertyType="String"/>'
```

That will return all the custom properties (as a Json String) which isSync should be in if set.

Comment: Thanks, however the most important part is: we have to use function 'Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync'  to see the properties from EWS after saving via 'customProps.saveAsync'. That was my mistake.